# Making contact form 7 dropdown mandatory

Tags: wordpress

```
[select* menu-76 first_as_blank "How did you hear about us*" "Google  " "Recommendation " "Checkatrade" "Social Media" "Returning customer" "Seen us on the road" "Advert" "Prefer not to say"]
```

I have added * just after the select but why this field is not working as mandatory? 
Please help..

Comment: `first_as_blank` does not exist as an option, according to documentation. `include_blank` and `first_as_label` are valid options.

Comment: AH....Thank you for the help :-)

Answer (score 5):

You need to insert "first_as_label", not "first_as_blank"

you can use "include_blank", this will include a blank field

```
[select* menu-76 first_as_label "How did you hear about us*" "Google  " "Recommendation " "Checkatrade" "Social Media" "Returning customer" "Seen us on the road" "Advert" "Prefer not to say"]
```

[Contact form 7 documentation here](https://contactform7.com/checkboxes-radio-buttons-and-menus/)

Comment: Thank you, have done that  :-) , thanks for the help.

Answer (score 5):

You need to add `include_blank` option in dropdown(select box) in contact form 7.
Code example.

```
[select* menu-76 include_blank "How did you hear about us*" "Google  " "Recommendation " "Checkatrade" "Social Media" "Returning customer" "Seen us on the road" "Advert" "Prefer not to say"]
```